# How to cut video length (Mp4)?

Tags: flash

I have situation I want the player to play the video from the beginning to only 15 sec, even the video length is more than 15 sec for example it will be about 10 min. but I only want it to play beginning 10 sec.

Is there a way for the flash player to only play 15 sec of the video? how is this work, and what function should I look for? is it also possible with HTML5 player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4 is a container format, but it commonly contains the .h264 / AAC payload, which is possible to play in Flash player. This format is also designed to be streamed, however, some programs may write it in a way it makes it impossible for the Flash player to progressively load or stream it. The problem is the placement of the metadata. Flash player requires that the metadata be placed at the beginning of the file. If you happen to have this problem, you can use ffmpeg + flvtool2 to inject the metadata in the proper place. Here's a decent explanation oh how to do it: http://www.ioncannon.net/web-design/109/metadata-cuepoint-flash-video-flvtool/ .

This being done, you would need to look at [NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/FileSystemComboBox.html#!flash/net/NetConnection.html) for connecting to the server serving the video. [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#!flash/net/NetStream.html) for actually managing the playback of the video. And [Video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#!flash/media/Video.html) for putting the video on display list. [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html#!flash/utils/Timer.html) is the class you will use for responding to time change. `NetStream.play()` / `NetStream.close()` in combination with `Timer` should do what you are asking for.

There are countless tutorials online on how to make a video player beside the examples you will find in the documentation. There are also many ready-made players with the open sources, so you can either use them as is, or learn from them and make your own.

Comment: what about html5 player? do you know any site that use html5 video player?